# How extract form elements from a textarea with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I tried to google it but nothing comes up. I have form builder with builds the form and generate a form structure. Then i will just copy paste that code into my textarea and save the whole html into mysql database. Now I want to modify that data and so I need to get the textarea value and filter it for input elements.

I used some thing like this.

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
    $("#btn").click(function(){
      $("#ta").each($('input,select,textarea', '#myform'),function(k){
              alert(k+' '+$(this).attr('name'));
       });
     });
   });
```

But its not shwoing me anything. I Know i am doing it wrong as i am not getting the textarea value first and than parse it. So i did somthing like this :

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
    $("#btn").click(function(){
      var a = $("#ta").val();
        a.each($('input,select,textarea', '#myform'),function(k){
        alert(k+' '+$(this).attr('name'));
       });
     });
   });
```

But this too not working. Any suggestions.

Comment: You should at first parse the textarea's value and then select the elements. Something like `$(a).find('whatever')` or `$('<div/>').html(a).find('whatever')`

Comment: It seems like you have multiple elements with the ID `ta`. This is invalid HTML — IDs **must** be unique.

Answer (score 0):

You have to parse the textarea's value (say `val1`) using `jquery` like `var a = $(val1)` and saving it in a variable then you can extract out any dom element you want.

like  `a.find('input[type="text"]')`

Comment: I tried to use it but my console shows me error that find is not a function.

Comment: can you please send me your jsfiddle that you tried

Answer (score 0):

You're calling each on a single element called with id="ta". Ids are only meant to be used once in a document. Since you didn't provide more sourcecode i cannot see if your issue is there. If it's a single element, what are you trying with the each?

```
$("#ta").each($('input,select,textarea', '#myform'),function(k){
    alert(k+' '+$(this).attr('name'));
});
```

I would suggest trying the following

```
$('input, select, textarea').each(function(k){
    alert(k+' '+$(this).attr('name'));
});
```